# Asp.net core keeps running the old build

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I am trying to build new project using ASP.NET Core 1.0 But the
problem is when i change the JavaScript code it does not reflect in
browser unless i rebuild them..

I can not figure out the problem. Is this VS2015 Update 3 bug.

If it's not a bug.. need help in resolving this issue. I cannot Build every time i change the code :)

Comment: Where is your JavaScript code located ? `wwwroot\js` ? Then the static file handler middleware will deliver the current file.

Comment: it is in `wwwroot` not in `wwwroot\js`

Comment: Is the file actually served from there or do you copy the JS files with a publish step? Is the content root actually set to the `wwwroot` folder under your project's folder and not some other `wwwroot` that publish creates?

Comment: the file is in `wwwroot\abc` folder

Comment: Do you use any task runner(such as `gulp`)?